# count number of folders with given name

Tags: python, path, operating-system

I am lookling to get count of folders and subfolders with a given name... Here I am searching for number of subfolders named "L-4"?  Returns zero and I am sure thats not true? What did I miss?

```
import os

path = "R:\\"

i = 0
for (path, dirs, files) in os.walk(path):
    if os.path.dirname == "L-4":
        i += 1

print i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.path.dirname` is a reference to [the standard library function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname), not a string. Perhaps you wanted to use `os.path.dirname(path)` instead here.

You could instead count how many times `L-4` appears in the `dirs` list:

```
i = 0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    i += dirs.count('L-4')
print i
```

or, as a one-liner:

```
print sum(dirs.count('L-4') for _, dirs, _ in os.walk(path))
```

Comment: Didn't you miss the squared brackets in your one-liner?

Comment: @miindlek: no, it is a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions).